# application is running but the MAP is Blank i am using google map api to locate some location

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

It shows me "Authentication failed on the server" error.
App runs without crashing but map is blank.Below i have pasted logcat and MainActivity class of my project.

This is MainActivity of my project

```
        static final LatLng TP = new LatLng(17.385044, 78.486671);
        private GoogleMap googleMap;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            try {
                // Loading map
                initilizeMap();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            /*
             * try { if (googleMap == null) { googleMap = ((MapFragment)
             * getFragmentManager() .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap(); }
             * googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
             * googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
             * TP).title("TP")); } catch (Exception e) {
             * e.printStackTrace(); }
             */
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onResume();
            initilizeMap();
        }

        /* function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you */
        private void initilizeMap() {
            if (googleMap == null) {
                googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                        R.id.map)).getMap();

                // check if map is created successfully or not
                if (googleMap == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

     ## Manifest ##

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.cell.track.activity"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="14"
            android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

        <permission
            android:name="com.example.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

        <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            <!-- Google MAP API key -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                android:value="AIzaSyA4cNBwKoRxmpW0qhMF8B_jBDpkkHaaSsQ" />
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

here is logcat:

```
01-05 11:34:22.841: E/b(24238): Authentication failed on the server.
        01-05 11:34:22.841: E/Google Maps Android API(24238): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
        01-05 11:34:22.851: E/Google Maps Android API(24238): In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
        01-05 11:34:22.851: E/Google Maps Android API(24238): Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
        01-05 11:34:22.851: E/Google Maps Android API(24238): Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
        01-05 11:34:22.851: E/Google Maps Android API(24238):   API Key: AIzaSyA4cNBwKoRxmpW0qhMF8B_jBDpkkHaaSsQ
        01-05 11:34:22.851: E/Google Maps Android API(24238):   Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): 90:A8:E0:F0:90:2F:93:73:C6:16:F0:10:B7:D8:2B:8A:24:08:48:7E;com.cell.track.activity
```

Comment: have you enabled api in developer console
??

Comment: yes i did but still the map is blank

Comment: is there any need or use of  google_maps_api.xml  file cause its not in my project is it inbuilt file.

Comment: what does that mean??

Comment: Have you added your application package and sha1 key correctly?

Comment: crash log says `Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setLocalOnly` which is available only in API level 20 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setLocalOnly(boolean)  and you may be testing it on device having API less than that. I think adding support libraries can help you out

Comment: why do i need to add support libaries cause the target sdk version is 22 @AZone

Comment: go thru http://stackoverflow.com/a/4568358/1206052 to know the difference and significance of  `target sdk`. you need support libraries so as to make the functionality available in higher api to the lower one. They provide so as that you can make use of new features in previous apis. Like for fragment is available in both the packages `import android.app.Fragment;` and `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.
You may have also noticed compiler warnings that this method is available in api X and above irrespective of the target sdk

Comment: how should i add the support libaries. @Azone

Comment: @Hari depends which IDE you are using . Google it you will get the solution there are different ways to add it to both Android studio and Eclipse. You can also follow http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: @Hari if it fixes your problem reply me, I will convert it to an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that you have added your map api key in your manifest. 
If you have create your api key correctly , then please make sure you have enabled google maps api from developers cosole.
 I have created a scenario where everything is right exceptt is not enabled . Shown the same error you got. Hope it helps.

Comment: i have added the api key in manifest but still its not working

Comment: i have added the files you asked have a look.  -----@Kris

Comment: is this file is required google_maps_api.xml cause i am using eclipse its not generated in my project

Comment: i had enabled the google map api it did not work @kris

Comment: Was it previously disabled?

Comment: IF you have enabled it now does it now show same crash log?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you didn't configure your project right in google developer console. I answered same question some days ago here on stackoverflow. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34555258/5275639) for answer. Follow all the steps mentioned there.

For eclipse. follow steps mentioned in this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/)

Comment: is there any need or use of google_maps_api.xml file cause its not in my project is it inbuilt file. @vivek mishra

Comment: yes you have to put your api key in google_maps_api.xml . If you use template for google maps in android studio , it will create that file automatically for you

Comment: if you generate MapActivity from android studio then you will find google_map_api.xml in values folders.

Comment: Is there any way to create this file in eclipse @zeeshan shabbir

Comment: I would recommend use android studio. And yes. You don't need to create  this file in eclipse. First you have to generate fingerprint using keytool then paste that along with your package into google console

Comment: And console will generate a key. copy it and store in string.xml file then use it in manifest. You are done

Answer (score -1):

**Permisions are given?**

```
<permission
        android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

**Key is added?** under application

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="abcsddkhashdkashdksadhaskdhsakd" />
```